# Do I need parenthesis around a simple IF in Transact SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have been coding all my simple IFs like this:

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1) 
    BEGIN
```

Is there any difference here between using and not using the parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the brackets around the simple IF clause, but it will be helpful when the If condition is complicated (while using AND / OR).